# iPhone 4 wifi stuck on off

Tags: iphone, ios

On my iphone 4 the wifi will sometimes be stuck on off. The button is grayed out and can't be slid back to on. This seems to happen at random. I've heard about this issue happening permanently, but on my phone, it's only occasionally. I'll open the phone up later and it will work again. Any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: Could be a cable not sitting properly. Define "open the phone up?"

Comment: Oh sorry, just meant going through the lock screen/using the phone.

Comment: Are you trying to turn off wifi in settings or control center (the one you swipe up from the bottom)

Comment: Settings. I can turn on/off from control center, but it won't actually turn on wifi if it's locked in settings.

Comment: Have you tried a restore via iTunes?

Comment: try this https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that can fix this other than hardware service, it's greyed out because the Wi-Fi module is not functioning correctly, it is intermittent now but will eventually fail entirely.

Your best course of action if you are under warranty is to take it to Apple, however this model is unlikely to be under the 1 year warranty, or 2 year AppleCare warranty.

In this case, if all of these apply to you:

- Bought the phone in the EU.
- Are the original purchaser of the unit.
- Bought for consumer use, not business
- Bought from Apple Online or an Apple Store

Then you can make a claim under EU Consumer Law which states a device should last a reasonable amount of time, however you are typically required to demonstrate this within the first 6 months. However this issue was a common failure mode for this product so I would suggest that it's a known issue to Apple and they should replace it under EU Consumer Law on the basis it is a known issue.

If one or more of the above don't apply or Apple refuses, then there is no option but a handset replacement, I wouldn't personally attempt a logic board replacement using parts online, it's a particularly complex repair.

**Source:** 6+ years working at Apple Retail